# vsnprintf from the exact value in array

Tags: c++, c, printf

is it possible to use vsnprintf to start printing from the exact value in the array?
For example, I would like to use vsnprintf to print from 25th character in the array.
Can I just this code?

```
va_list args;
#define length 100
char debug[length];
va_start(args, fmt);
vsnprintf(debug[25], length, fmt, args);
a_debug(devh,debug);
va_end(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Print *from* 25th character? You mean print *into* the buffer starting at the 25th byte position? Try this:

```
vsnprintf(debug + 25, length - 25, fmt, args);
```